# How to adjust width and height of UIImageView depending on image download from url in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to create custom UITableViewCell using autolayout which contain UIImageView and UILabel which is at the bottom of UIImageView. In it download image through url and adjust its height and width depending on dimensions of image downloaded from url. In that I am dowloading image using SDWebImage.

Comment: you need to add custom tableview cell class.

Comment: I have already added it

Comment: so now what problem you have ?

Comment: I want to adjust width and height of UIImageView depending on image downloaded and adjust UILabel below UIImagevIew

Comment: create object of that custom cell and set frame of image view in cellForRowatIndexpath  like cell.yourlable.frame = your frame. cell.yourimageview.fram = imageframe.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the table view cell height inside the delegate method

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return height;
  }

Return the height of your image. If you need more info see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:).